# ER Diagram School Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I've made a ER Diagram using the Chen Notation and using a casus. Could anyone check if I'm doing it the right way?

Besides this I have some other questions:

Why does the weak entity always has one and one only? (thick arrow form assignments to has)

How do I process the salary between 20 times the scale and 35 times the scale in a ER Diagram?

I hope someone can help me

The ER Diagram I've made so far

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITOzc.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "x times the scale"?

Comment: I mean that the salary of a teacher is x times his scale & this value must be between 20 and 35. Scale is an attribute of the teacher

Answer (score 0):

ER diagram means  Entity-Relationship diagram. 
you can not write there about the process on Attributes.
you can do salary's scaling regarding a process in a query.